# Xquery is returning result for one set of elements but not others?

Tags: java, xml, xpath, xquery

I have the following `XML`:

```
<Details>
    <Detail>
        <name>Detail one</name>
        <id>001</id>
    </Detail>
    <Detail>
        <name>Detail two</name>
        <id>002</id>
    </Detail>
</Details>
```

I am querying this by Name to get ID using an `XQuery` Service with a `Java` method:

```
 public String getIdByName(String detailName) {
        final String detail_Name = detailName;
        return engine.new Query<String>(DETAILS_COLLECTION) {

            @Override
            protected String query(Collection collection) throws Exception {
                XQueryService service = queryService();

                ResourceSet resourceSet = service.query(
                        format("//Details/Detail[name='%s']" +
                                        "/id/text()"
                                , StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml(detailName)

                        ));

                List<String> ids = newArrayList();

                for (String resource : new IterableStringResources(resourceSet)) {
                    instanceLocations.add(resource);
                }
                return ids.get(0);
            }
        }.execute();
}
```

This method correctly returns an id for this `XML` section with name "Detail one":

```
<Detail>
    <name>Detail one</name>
    <id>001</id>
<Detail>
```

But does **not** return values for the 2nd one with name "Detail two":

```
<Detail>
    <name>Detail two</name>
    <id>002</id>
</Detail>
```

What could be causing this?

Comment: This is not `XQuery`, this is more `XPath`

Comment: I cannot reproduce with `XPATH`, are you sure that you use "Detail two" maybe it is "detail two" or "detail"? You need to provide simple code to reproduce cf [MVCE rule](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Yeah AFAICT his XPath expression is OK. To OP: please provide a [MCVE] or a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/) that shows the problem.

Comment: @java123999 please help us to help you by providing the minimal to reprocude

Comment: @NicolasFilotto _"This is not XQuery, this is more XPath"_ - just in case you're interested: XQuery is a superset of XPath, which means that an XPath expression is a valid XQuery query. Original poster: the question is: what are the actual input strings and what does `StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml` do to them? Print `StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml(detailName)` to see what `%s` is actually replaced with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing about your code looks incorrect, so I would suspect your input. You could try sanitizing it before running the query:

```
"//Details/Detail[name=fn:normalize-space('%s')]"
```

However, this will only fix problems with whitespace. You still need to be sure you don't have a misspelling or unexpected punctuation.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a bit late for you now but your return statement at the end:

```
return ids.get(0);
```

That is specifically asking for index 0.

If you change it to simply:

```
return ids;
```

That should return them all rather that just the first index.

I was having a similar problem which is why I just stumbled upon this.